# Source of the no. of isomers in alkanes, and other organic molecules

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would like to ask if there is a source where I can find all the isomers for the alkanes, or other organic molecules. With other words, a list where each molecule of that group is stated in ascending order, and beside there is a value for the no. of isomers it can form.

Comment: Search around a bit $\ldots$ There are similar questions about this now. All of them say "it ain't that easy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not counting stereoisomers and enantiomers, the number of isomers of the first ten alkanes is as follows:

1. Methane: 1
2. Ethane: 1
3. Propane: 1
4. Butane: 2
5. Pentane: 3
6. Hexane: 5
7. Heptane: 9
8. Octane: 18
9. Nonane: 35
10. Decane: 75

Source: http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/21/tm1121.pdf and Wikipedia articles for these alkanes. The PDF has the number of isomers for the first 30 n-alkanes.

The number of isomers possible with an n-carbon alkane can be calculated by a recursive combinatorial function; however, as the linked paper states, this math isn't for the weak. The number of structural isomers of a 30-carbon alkane is over 4 billion, and a 50-carbon alkane has over 10<sup>31</sup> possible isomers. Even organic chemists and petrochemists usually don't bother to identify any one isomer beyond about the pentane mark. Some of the more symmetrical isomers are interesting on their own, since a few of the more compact ones (like the n-methyl types) have markedly different behaviors such as boiling point from longer isomers (for example, tetramethylbutane, an isomer of octane notable for its relatively narrow liquid window). The 2,2-dimethylpropane isomer of pentane is visually interesting because of its isohedral geometry, and likewise the tetraethylmethane/diethylpentane isomer might find interest among a few supremacist groups but is otherwise just another 9-carbon alkane.

Comment: There are a lot of "impossible" alkanes included in that numbers. Impossible due to too much crowding in some places. But to calculate this number I do not have the meanest idea. Finding conformers and calculating their energy is a time consuming business even on the fastest computers.

Comment: So, there are now ways of calculating the no. of isomers without a computer?

Comment: Per the linked article, the original computations were done by hand; however there was an error made in those calculations which was not found and fixed until the calculations were re-run with a supercomputer in the 1980s. Theoretically, any math that a computer can do, a human can do slower. Realistically, when you're not only computing ideal combinations, but also computing the chemical shapes and thus the distortion of bond angles and lengths from the ideal caused by "overcrowding" to determine the feasibility of that isomer, it becomes totally infeasible to do it all on paper.

Answer (score 0):

KeithS's answer is good for the saturated alkanes (generic formula $\ce{C_{n}H_{2n +2}}$). For other organic molecules...

Introducing unsaturation or heteroatoms makes it even more complicated. There are two "possible" structures for $\ce{C3H6}$ - [propene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propene) and [cyclopropane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropane) and three for $\ce{C3H4}$ - [propyne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propyne), [allene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allene), and [cyclopropene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cyclopropene).

While $\ce{C4H10}$ has two isomers, [butane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butane) and [isobutane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobutane), $\ce{C4H10O}$ has seven: [1-butanol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-butanol), [2-butanol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Butanol), [isobutanol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobutanol), [*tert*-butanol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tert-Butanol), [diethyl ether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deithyl_ether), [methyl propyl ether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_propyl_ether), and [methyl isopropyl ether](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.11228.html). For $\ce{C4H8O}$, there are at least 23 valid structures, not including stereoisomers, although not all of them are stable molecules (enols, I am looking at you!).

Beyond maybe 5 or so heavy atoms, the whole effort becomes futile as the number of isomers increases exponentially. Instead, try Googling the formula you care about. ChemSpider will list all known/reported compounds with a given formula. For $\ce{C4H8O}$, there are 42 [entries including stereoisomers](http://www.chemspider.com/Search.aspx?rid=371e2471-8194-4fec-b7ec-3cbf0521b8d9).